# Does the Xamarin.iOS garbage collector use a fixed MaxGeneration?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, garbage-collection

In my tests, Xamarin.iOS always seems to use two generations. That is, `GC.MaxGeneration` always returns `1`. The [Xamarin Cross-Platform Performance Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/memory_perf_best_practices/#sgen) seems to support that by referring to the [Mono SGen Documentation](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/garbage-collector/sgen/), which states the *SGen* uses two generations. On the other hand, the [Xamarin API Documentation of GC.MaxGeneration](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/System.GC.MaxGeneration/) suggests that MaxGeneration can increase over time.

Is `GC.MaxGeneration` fixed in Xamarin.iOS, or can it increase given enough time?

Also, just in case: Has the behaviour changed in the last year? Reason for this question: Alongside the [current stable release of Xamarin iOS](https://releases.xamarin.com/category/stable/), we are using [Cycle 6 Service Release 4](https://releases.xamarin.com/stable-release-cycle-6-service-release-4/) for bugfixes for an older product.