# Is it possible to log when a major garbage collection occurs in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, garbage-collection

In Xamarin.iOS, is it possible to log:

- ... when a major garbage collection occurs?
- ... how long the major garbage collection took?

With logging, I mean using `Console.WriteLine`, or a custom logging implementation creating a linear log of text lines with time stamps.

The `GC.RegisterForFullGCNotification(Int32, Int32)` and `GC.WaitForFullGC*()` API is not implemented on Xamarin.iOS (as of the [current stable release](https://releases.xamarin.com/stable-release-15-2-3-xamarin-vs-servicing-release/), and also not on [Cycle 6 Service Release 4](https://releases.xamarin.com/stable-release-cycle-6-service-release-4/), which we are still using for bugfixes for an older product).

I've had success polling `GC.CollectionCount(1)` (collection count for generation one) with high frequency. But this only gives me the information that a major collection did recently occur. Also, that's making the assumption that a major collection indeed is the collection for generation one (compare [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45409233/)).

Are there other possibilities to log garbage collection details in Xamarin.iOS? Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set Mono environment variables to output the GC info. These can be temp or permanent.

- http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/runtime/logging-runtime-events/

Permanent env. vars are set via iOS Build options (`mtouch`) and are burned into the app and thus the deployed `ipa`

```
--setenv:MONO_LOG_LEVEL=info  --setenv:MONO_LOG_MASK=gc
```

[image]

Temp. env vars for debugging purposes are set via `Run Configuration`.

Output:

```
2017-07-31 02:35:30.425 SushiHangover.FlightAvionics[88235:10243737] info: GC_MAJOR: (user request) time 0.90ms, stw 1.29ms los size: 1024K in use: 10K
2017-07-31 02:35:30.426 SushiHangover.FlightAvionics[88235:10243737] info: GC_MAJOR_SWEEP: major size: 1184K in use: 479K
```